# Webpack angular2 compiling error

Tags: typescript, compilation, angular, webpack

Hi I am trying to compile angular2 with Webpack, all seems to work fine a part that I get this error

```
nodecrm/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts
(1406,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'msCrypto'.
```

I was following angular website guid https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html
is there something that I am missing? My tsconfig.json file looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
    "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "typings/browser",
            "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: I have the exact same error on an old project built on angular2 and webpack. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I have the exact same error on an old project built on angular2 and webpack. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was caused by the `angular2-universal-polyfills` package that contains an old version of the `reflect-metadata` package.
I've fixed it by downloading the actual reflect-metadata with npm:

```
npm install reflect-metadata
```

Then copied the node_modules\reflect-metadata folder into the node_modules\angular2-universal-polyfills\node_modules folder, rewriting the old one there.

Hope this helps someone facing this issue. I was working on an old project with angular2.4.5 and webpack.

Comment: This worked for me for development, but when I publish in Visual Studio, it rebuilds the resources, so the publication fails. I don't know how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Latest tsconfig.json from webpack introduction article looks like below-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Try changing to this. See if this helps.

Comment: Nope this doesn't help, I've tried almost all different combinations of the tsconfig, but no success. Also reinstalled the angular and that problematic lib reflect-metadata but still no success.

Comment: Which IDE you are using? Webstorm ? If yes, then explicitly use below code- 

/// <reference path="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect-metadata.d.ts" />

import '../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect';

Comment: No it's Atom, I've tried this as well, produces even more errors. I think the problem is in typings probably there is no definition for this module msCrypto and the comillator can't recognise it. Before I had a similar error, and I had to just find the right typing with typings search [module]  and then install it. but I now when I search for msCrypto there is no any record for this module.

Comment: I am able to run Angular2 RC2 webpack introduction application on my machine. My environment is - Windows7 64bit OS, VScode 1.2.1, node v4.4.5, npm v3.9.5 and chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `reflect-metadata` package has a dependency over `crypto` so install them as,

`npm install reflect-metadata crypto --save`